# window.print() function doesn't show the checked value of radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I tried `window.print()` function to print the page and this does not print the checked values of radio buttons

```js
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#">
  <p><label><input checked name="group1" style="display: block" type="radio"> <span style="color:blue">Red</span></label></p>
  <p><label><input name="group1" type="radio"> <span>Yellow</span></label></p>
  <p><label><input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio"> <span>Green</span></label></p>
</form><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id='printButton' onclick="myFunction()">&nbsp;Print&nbsp;</button>
```

On clicking the print button the printed page should have the radio button checked.

Comment: Unable to reproduce so voting to close until you provide a min reproducible example

Comment: Can't reproduce either.

Comment: When I select print it appears to show the correct checked `radio` button.

Comment: What browser are you running this on?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what is being printed and maybe create a second image of what you expect to be printed? Everything seems to be working fine from the example you have provided so I feel something could be missing that might be found from the screenshot/images. Thank you.

Comment: @chevybow I forgot to add a part of the code so it worked previously, now I have made changes and now you can view the error.

Comment: @NewToJS I have made few changes to the code and now you can view the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a materialize lib issue.
Active radio button has a very weird print style.
You can write own styles, something like this:

```
@media print {
    input[type="radio"]:checked+span { 
        font-weight: bold; 
    }
}
```

Or add with-gap class to all radio buttons.

```
 class="with-gap"
```

materialize issue: 
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6175

Comment: Thank you so much, your comment and the link for the materializecss issue helped me to solve my problem !!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue with Angular Material v9, Chrome v81. The problem is the "check" in the radio button (and checkboxes) doesn't show if background images are turned off, which they seem to be by default in Chrome.

Adding the following to your stylesheet will solve the problem:

```
 -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
```

Should work for Materialize as well.